# Required services that are not installed when use resource-ref in JBoss7.1

Tags: java, configuration, jboss, migration, jndi

I'm migratin app from WebLogic to JBoss application server. And I need to leave JNDI names for JMS in code be the same as I have with WebLogic. For this I try to use resource-ref in web.xml and jboss-web.xml file. But always get error:

```
 "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.connect.connect-ejb.ConnectCGMPeriodicMessageBean.env.jms.ConnectConnectionFactory",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.connect.connect-ejb.ConnectCGMPeriodicMessageBean.env.jms.ConnectSMSQueue"
    ]
```

My suggestion that resource-ref not working with MDB from another module.
Because if I add MDB in connect-api (web module) - resource-ref works well.
Maybe I need to do resource-ref on jar or ear level? And how can I do that?
For test purpose I also created a simple web project to test and there resource-ref works good.

I have multi-module application and packaged in one ear file.
application.xml of ear:

```
<module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>connect-api.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/api/connect/v1</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>connect-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
```

In connect-ejb.jar module I have Message Driven Bean :

```
@MessageDriven
@RequestScoped
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class ConnectCGMPeriodicMessageBean extends AbstractConnectBean {
 @Resource(mappedName = "jms/ConnectConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory m_factory;
    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/ConnectSMSQueue")
    private Queue m_queue;
}
```

web.xml of connect-api.war module :

```
  <resource-ref>
            <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>
        <resource-ref>
            <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectSMSQueue</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.jms.Queue</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>
```

jboss-web.xml of connect-api.war module :

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
        <jndi-name>java:/jms/ConnectConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectSMSQueue</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.jms.Queue</res-type>
        <jndi-name>java:/jms/ConnectSMSQueue</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
```

in standalone-full.xml I add :

```
  <jms-queue name="jms/ConnectSMSQueue" entries="java:/jms/ConnectSMSQueue"/>
                          <connection-factory name="jms/ConnectConnectionFactory" entries="java:/jms/ConnectConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution , need add to jboss-ejb3.xml :

```
 <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>ConnectPumpPeriodicMessageBean</ejb-name>
        <resource-ref>
            <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
            <lookup-name>java:/jms/ConnectConnectionFactory</lookup-name>
        </resource-ref>
        <resource-ref>
            <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectSMSQueue</res-ref-name>
            <lookup-name>java:/jms/ConnectSMSQueue</lookup-name>
        </resource-ref>
    </message-driven>
```